# need to display page header on condition based in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

> we have a requirement to display page header for 1 tablix only  (we
>   have 2 tablix) we need to display page header in 1st tablix only even
>   if record repeats in multiple pages and i do not want to show page
>   header for page 2.
>
> **
>   **eg**:**

**

> **like if we have 4 pages and data comes for 1st tablix in 3 pages out
>   of 4 then page header should display on 1st three pages not in 4th
>   page.**
>
> i have tried this
>
> intially i was page header in the report which has limitation of
>   repeating page header based on the condition so i moved my page header
>   content in the tablix row for the 1st tablix but it's not repating for
>   all the content in all the pages

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. There is no example.

Comment: eg:like if we have 4 pages and data comes for 1st tablix in 3 pages out of 4 then page header should display on 1st three pages not in 4th page.

Comment: pls tell what more info. you require !!

Comment: seems you don't require header here... you need to add simple tablix with outside grope above textbox.

Answer (score 0):

If it is something that hiding report page-header or footer only for particular page ? , You can hide/show the items if you put them inside the rectangle and set the visibility expression to hide/show based on page number. 
But I think that what you want is that you only want to display the report header where there is data from the tablix. What about having the tablix header outside the group like pedram suggested? I think it is more manageable.